# Telling yourself lashon hara

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander

There are several websites that let you send an email to yourself in the future ([example](https://www.futureme.org/)).  It's also possible to accomplish something similar in a lower-tech way, like making a time capsule.

Are you allowed to tell lashon hara to yourself?  In particular, if someone did something bad that you'll probably forget in 50 years, are you allowed to remind yourself of it using one of these websites?

I'm assuming a situation where לא תקם ולא תטר doesn't apply.  You're reminding yourself for a valid reason, but not necessarily complying with all the [conditions listed by the Chafetz Chaim](https://seferchofetzchaim.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/dcompanion-the-seven-rules-of-toeles/).

An example would be a case where someone 50 years older than you did something that older people might be prone to.  You're afraid that in 50 years, when you're that age, you might end up doing the same thing, so you send an email to remind yourself not to.  Do you have to follow the 7 conditions?  For instance, can you exaggerate a little if you think that will be more persuasive to your 50-years-older self?

Comment: Isn't writing lashon hara equivalent to saying lashon hara? Even if you write it to yourself and toss it in the trash immediately? You said - " You're reminding yourself for a valid reason" - What is this valid reason? How would you know that the same person would be dangerous in 50 years?

Comment: @DanF I assumed the problem was saying lashon hara to a person, meaning writing it and throwing it in the trash would be ok (assuming nobody reads it by accident - maybe shredding it would be a better idea).  Do you have a source that saying lashon hara when nobody is around is a problem?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm a bit unclear about what example could fit this case. It's almost mutually inclusive: if there's a reason that it's not Lo Tikom/Lo Titor, then that same reason should make it not Lashon Hara.

Comment: I don't, offhand. Something I understood. I'll see if I can research. That's why I asked. But, I'm still not seeing the "usefulness" aspect.

Comment: @DanF Let's say someone 50 years older than you did something wrong that's more relevant for older people, and you're afraid of falling into the same trap in 50 years, so you write an email to remind yourself not to.

Comment: @Salmononius2 ^^^

Comment: I see your example. To me, that makes it more problematic, actually. People change in 50 years. If anything this seems very much like a case of "lo tisnah et achicha bilvavecha". Why didn't you use *hoche'ach tochiach* 50 years ago, or even now?

Comment: In that example, that would fall under the category of Toeles then (ignoring the (sound) objections raised by @DanF for now. I agree that 50 years is a long time and circumstances probably change, but for arguments sake we'll say it doesn't). If you have reason to believe that the issue is something that you need to be aware of 50 years from now, then that's the L'Toeles to permit Lashon Hara

Comment: @DanF no, you misunderstood.  The person who's 50 years older than you did something wrong.  You are afraid that you'll end up doing the same thing in 50 years, not of someone hurting you in 50 years.

Comment: @Salmononius2 yes, it's a toeles, but do you still need the 7 conditions?  Let's take condition (4) "One is not permitted to exaggerate in any way. This can be especially difficult in a situation where one is relating information regarding an emotional issue."  Maybe you think the email will be more persuasive to you in the future if you exaggerate a little.  If it's to someone else, you can't.  If it's to yourself, maybe you can.

Comment: Ah, I think I may have misunderstood your example earlier as well. I'll reiterate what I said earlier, but with more conviction this time: interesting. :) I'm still a little skeptical on the situation. Why couldn't the email just be a bit genericised so it won't be Lashon Hara? (Although per your comment, you're asking based on the premise that being specific is more effective, so my question is basically a Kasha on a Ma'aseh...)

Comment: +1 This is a cute question. When I saw the title I thought it was going to be some type of tree in a forest questing. This is nice.

Comment: As an aside, perhps you should edit some of these clarifications into the question so that these comments could be cleaned out a bit.

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/987699/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-saying-lashon-hara-about-yourself/ - this might help, check it out